# why would $form_id be an array instead of a string?

Tags: 7, forms, hooks

```
function my_custom_form_alter(&$form, $form_id) {
  sdpm($form_id);
}
```

This is giving me large arrays that include a line like this:

```
$form_id['build_info']['form_id']
```

So technically I *can* access the ID via `$form_id['build_info']['form_id']` but it seems like a bad idea to write that in my module.

$form_id is an array, not a string as [the docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) say it should be.

What could possibly be going on here?

Has anyone ever seen this before?

Comment: The 2nd param to a form alter hook is `$form_state` - an array. `$form_id` is third

Comment: Your function needs to be `function my_custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {`

Comment: wow, I guess this is a basic lesson in how function in php work?  I didn't realize these parameters work based on their order and not their name.  Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what to do regarding "answering" or closing this question since the answer is in your comment though...?